# vcov for lda in R

Tags: r, covariance, variance

I have performed a linear discriminant analysis with the lda command:

```
n=1000
library(wakefield)
y<-c("D", "ND")[r_sample_binary(n)]
x_1<-rnorm(n,0,1)
x_2<-rnorm(n,0,1)
x_3<-rnorm(n,3,2)
x_4<-rnorm(n,2,2)
x_5<-rnorm(n,0,1)
df<-data.frame(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,y)
y<-as.factor(y)
train=(x_1<1) # training sample criterion
df.test=df[!train,] # define test sample
y.test=y[!train]
library(MASS) # load the needed library
lda.mod=lda(y~x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5, data=df, subset=train)
```

In addition to the output of lda.mod, I would like to have also the estimated variance covariance matrix of the coefficients (I know it is know in this case, but I just want to simulate its calculation).
When using vcov I get an error message:

```
vcov(lda.mod)
Error in UseMethod("vcov") : 
  no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "qda"
```

Is there a workaround to this problem?